# Older book about one-way time travel to age of dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification

It's a vintage, 1950's or 1960's era novel.

The story is told in a framing device, of the discovery of some kind of manuscript excavated from rock. It is an impossible artifact, and tells the story of an accidental time traveler who got zapped back to the age of dinosaurs.
The story itself is told in first person, of encountering ancient flora, gigantic insects, and being hunted by carnivorous dinosaurs. It's startlingly realistic -- this isn't a conquering hero, but a marooned scientist, trying his best to survive, and the ending is rather downbeat: injured, without antibiotics, slowly dying.

The framing device ends with the scientists who discover the artifact quietly hiding the existence of the manuscript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The time doesn't match, but otherwise this sounds somewhat like [*The Dechronization of Sam Magruder*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2093652) (1996) by George Gaylord Simpson.

Quoting from the blurb on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/57234):

> Vanishing from Earth on February 30, 2162, while working on a problem of quantum theory, **research chronologist Sam Magruder is thrown back 80 million years in time**. Endowed with the intelligence of a twenty-second-century man, Magruder struggles to survive, feeding on scrambled turtle eggs and **diligently recording his observations on a stone-slab diary**, even as menacing tyrannosaurus try to gnaw off his limbs.

In addition, however, to the date being off, the story lacks the detail of the story being suppressed.  Indeed the framing story, the presentation of the slabs, their history and content, to the representative group of specialists (and the Common Man) by the Universal Historian, is to determine the best way to reveal the existence, content and meaning of the slabs to the world at large.

The story ends:

> The accident—well, it had to happen sooner or later.  I suppose I've slowed down, and perhaps I've become a little careless.  I've dodged so many dinosaurs.  I dodged one too many, and was careless once too often.  The brute—it was a tyrannosaur—got me by the leg.  Fortunately, you might say, he shook me loose, tearing off the leg at the knee, and he didn't see where the rest of me fell.  I tied up the stump and crawled away, but I'm done.  That was yesterday and I can't last much more than another day at best.
>
> There; the first seven slabs are safe, as safe as I can manage.
>
> There isn't much more to say.  I've had no joy, but a little satisfaction, from this long ordeal.  I have often wondered why I kept going.  That, at least, I have learned and I know it now at the end.  There could be no hope and no reward.  I always recognized that bitter truth.  But I am a man, and a man is responsible for himself.
>
> ["May he rest in peace," said the Common Man.  For once,
> no one else said anything.]

You can read *The Dechronization of Sam Magruder* at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/dechronizationof00simp/page/n25/mode/2up) (free, sign-up required).

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks!

The author, a paleontologist, died in 1984, so his writing style was somewhat 50's or 60's-ish. And I completely mis-remembered the ending -- the time traveller's tale isn't locked away, but the framing is how to disseminate it.

Comment: You are most welcome!

Comment: This makes me curious if that story inspired the 1970's Saturday Morning Kid's show [Land of the Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_the_Lost_(1974_TV_series)). Looking at the WP page, it appears that a lot of Sci-Fi luminaries participated in it.

Answer (score 16):

Is this ***[The Dechronization of Sam Magruder](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57234.The_Dechronization_of_Sam_Magruder)*** (1996) by George Gaylord Simpson...?

The story was written some time prior to the author's death in 1984, but was published posthumously after it was discovered by his daughter.

From a [review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-312-13963-6):

> This intelligent, if conventional time-travel yarn, which was found by the daughter of the eminent paleontologist Simpson (d. 1984), shows some of the crusty wit of his idiosyncratic autobiography, Concessions to the Improbable. **Simpson tells the tale of Sam Magruder, a 22nd-century scientist who slips back to the late Cretaceous period. In this "Crusoe of the Cretaceous," as Clarke dubs it in his appreciative introduction, Magruder's struggle to maintain his mental composure in utter isolation is as important as his struggle for survival among the saurians. In the manner of H.G. Wells's Time Machine, the tale is framed by present-day (in this case, 22nd-century) interlocutors, who try to make sense of Magruder's record, which has been found by a geologist.** Simpson uses the story to advance his preferred hypotheses about dinosaurs, most notably that they were cold-blooded and slow (a vision that has come under increasing attack since the 1960s, according to Gould's afterword), but he doesn't sacrifice storytelling to pedantry. When Magruder is shocked at the gleaming white teeth of a T-rex--he'd previously known only fossil-brown--the thought is shocking to the reader, too. The end, which involves an epiphany Sam has when trapping small, shrew-like mammals for their fur, is comic and oddly moving at once: he realizes, with a sense of both awe and the ridiculous, that the creature is his ``Great-grandpa.''